# How to transpose date column value as column name in MySQL Group By query

Tags: mysql, group-by, pivot

TABLE STRUCTURE:

```
ID    NAME    SUM_HOURS   WEEK

1     name1     32        2018-01-01
1     name1     30        2018-02-01
1     name1     35        2018-03-01
```

Below is my Query for above table:

```
SELECT id                                    id,
e.name                                       name,
SUM(f.hours)                                 sum_hours,
fc.from_date                                 week,
FROM factdaily f, finance_calendar_full  fc, employee e
WHERE f.date                    = fc.date
AND f.emp_id                    = e.id 
AND f.date                   >= valid_from
AND f.date                   <= valid_to       
GROUP BY week
HAVING sum_hours > 0
```

DESIRED TABLE STRUCTURE:

```
ID NAME    2018-01-01 2018-02-01 2018-03-01
1  name1   32         30          35
```

Any help is much appreciated as i way not able to figure out.

Comment: What's your mysql version

Comment: lookup pivot tables, but its best to just handle this in your application.

Comment: Server version: 10.3.1-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server @D-Shih